# Dragging a group of elements and zooming in D3

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I was able to incorporate the [Pan/Zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999) example fine. The problem is I also want to be able to drag various groups of elements in addition to zooming. What I'm doing now, is disabling the "pan" part of the zoom/drag behavior, and having a separate drag event listener on the groups I want the user to be able to drag. The problem now is that when I drag a group, then go to zoom in, the group jumps. I was wondering what the best way to go about fixing this problem might be? I was thinking about changing all of the individual elements positions' directly instead of just translating the whole group, but that seems really brittle and inefficient to me.

EDIT: Here is my code. I've commented the pertinent parts, but left the whole directive for context

```
window.angular.module('ngff.directives.board', [])
      .directive('board', ['socket',
function(socket) {


  var linker = function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var nodeDragging = false;


    scope.svg = d3.select(elem[0]).append("svg")
      .attr('width', elem.parent().width())
      .attr('height', elem.parent().height())
      .attr('class', 'boardBackground')
      .on('mouseup', function(){
        nodeDragging = false;
      })
      .append('g')
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', zoom))
      .append('g')

    scope.svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", elem.parent().width())
      .attr("height", elem.parent().height());

    scope.$on('addFormation', function(event, formation) {
      var group = formation.select('g');
      scope.svg.node().appendChild(group.node())
      var pieces = group.selectAll('circle')
        .on('mousedown', function(){
          //Here I set a flag so I can check for node dragging when my zoom function is called
          nodeDragging = true;
        })
        .call(d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', move));
    })

    function move() {
      var dragTarget = d3.select(this);
      dragTarget
        .attr('cx', function() {
          return d3.event.dx + parseInt(dragTarget.attr('cx'))
        })
        .attr('cy', function() {
          return d3.event.dy + parseInt(dragTarget.attr('cy'))
        })
    }

    //******I return here if the user is dragging the node to keep all of the elements from being  translated
    function zoom() {
      if(nodeDragging)return
      console.log('zoom')
      scope.svg
      .attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: linker
  }

}
])
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Have you tried using separate zoom behaviours for each group to allow dragging them separately, but setting the zoom globally? I.e. in the handler you would set `translate` for the group, but `scale` for the entire SVG (and update for the other zoom behaviours as well).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean they jump? And I second what Lars said. It doesn't seem like you are translating the zoom event which may be causing some things to "jump" when zooming in.